# Compare two files without sorting them using shell script

Tags: bash, unix, cmp

I have two files : `filea` and `fileb` which I don't want to sort (so I can't use `comm`).

```
filea    fileb
cat      cat
dog      elephant
cat      snake
rabbit   pony
```

If the content of `filea` is same as that of `fileb` then display what is in `fileb`, if the contents of files are different and file2 contains elephant then display `ele`, if snake, then display `sna`, if pony then display `pon`.

I tried using `cmp`:

```
if cmp -s filea fileb
then echo $"fileb"
fi
```

but it didn't display anything. I want the output to be in a column in a third file.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to print `fileb` if it's the same as `filea`.  If those are different, you want to print the first 3 characters of the lines that are not present in `filea`.  The following should work for you:

```
$ cmp -s filea fileb && cat fileb || { grep -v -f filea fileb | cut -c-3; }
ele
sna
pon
```

(The paraphrased question above is, indeed, the explanation for the expression above.)

Comment: Nice demonstration of the UNIX philosophy +1.

Comment: grep -f : illegal option that's what it is displaying

Comment: @user2613272 Which platform are you on?  It seems that your version of `grep` doesn't support `-f`.  If you're on Solaris, you might have a version `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` that supports the option.

Comment: @user2613272 Check if using `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` instead of `grep` works for you.

Comment: it worked but the output did cut all what is in file b ; that means if the 2 files are the same , file2 is not displayed completely

Comment: @user2613272 It seems that you made some sort of copy/pasting error.

Comment: i tried cmp -s filea fileb && cat fileb alone and didn't display anything

Comment: @user2613272 `cmp -s filea fileb && cat fileb` would output anything if the two files are identical.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` without sorting either file:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' filea fileb
elephant
snake
pony
```

Print just the first 3 characters of the differences:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a){print substr($0,1,3)}' filea fileb
ele
sna
pon
```

For the ouput to be in a new file use redirection:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a){print substr($0,1,3)}' filea fileb > filec
```

**EDIT:**

```
FNR==NR       # Are we looking at the first file
a[$0]         # If so build an associative array of the file
next          # Go get the next line in the file
!($0 in a)    # In the second file now, check if the current line is in the array
print sub...  # If not print the first 3 characters from the current line
```

Comment: can you please explain the steps ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAICR, `cmp` returns true if the files are the same.  Therefore it is not surprising that the `if` statement printed nothing; the files are different.  You need an `else` clause that finds the three words in `file2` and truncates them to just three characters:

```
if cmp -s filea fileb
then cat fileb
else
    {
    grep elephant fileb
    grep snake fileb
    grep pony fileb
    } |
    sed 's/\(...\).*/\1/'
fi
```

Comment: The `sed` command remembers 3 characters (the first 3) and also matches any extra characters on the line, but replaces the whole lot with just the remembered ones.